# Show category id in confirm order

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

How to show category id in confirm order Opencart 2.

Thanks.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut5zF.png)

Comment: To avoid a bad start in the Stack Overflow community I recommend you to review [How do i ask a good question?] . Good questions brings good answers, unfortunately your question might be seem clear to you but it is not really.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the following changed.

1. Open the file **`catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php`**. Find the line `$this->load->model('extension/extension');` and add this after it. `$this->load->model('catalog/product');`
2. Replace this

   ```
   $data['products'][] = array(
           'key'        => $product['key'],
           'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
           'name'       => $product['name'],
           'model'      => $product['model'],
           'option'     => $option_data,
           'recurring'  => $recurring,
           'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
           'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
           'price'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))),
           'total'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity']),
           'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']),
   );
   ```

BY THIS

```
$cats = $this->model_catalog_product->getCatByProd($product['product_id']);

$prefix = '';

foreach ($cats as $cat){
    $categories .= $prefix.$cat['category_id'];
    $prefix = ', ';
}

    $data['products'][] = array(
            'key'        => $product['key'],
            'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
            'categories' => $categories,
            'name'       => $product['name'],
            'model'      => $product['model'],
            'option'     => $option_data,
            'recurring'  => $recurring,
            'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
            'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
            'price'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))),
            'total'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity']),
            'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']),
    );
```

3. OPEN THIS FILE **`catalog/model/catalog/product.php`**. Add this function inside it.

   ```
   public function getCatByProd($product_id) {
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

           return $query->rows;
   }
   ```
4. OPEN THIS FILE **`catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\confirm.tpl`**.

Replace this

```
<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
```

BY THIS

```
<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name'].' ('.$product['categories'].')'; ?></a>
```

Comment: not working. In step 6 confirmation order show this alert. https://yadi.sk/i/KwdfHInDsQnDE